# React Component cannot read props of parent - returns null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
// ClientDisplay.js

class ClientDisplay extends Component {

  ...

  render() {

    const {activeClient} = this.props

    console.log(activeClient); // This works fine

    const clientGroupMenu = (
      <div>
        <SelectMenu
          defaultValue={activeClient.groupName}
          ...
    )

    return (
      <div>{clientGroupMenu}</div>
    )

  }
}

export default ClientDisplay

// View.js

export class View extends Component {

  ...

  render(){
    return (
      <ClientDisplay
         {...this.props}
      />
    )
  }
  ...
}
```

As you can see the line `console.log(activeClient)` logs the correct data.

However I get an error on `defaultValue={activeClient.groupName}`

`index.es.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null`

I also get the same error if I use `defaultValue={this.props.activeClient.groupName}`

Does anyone know why I cannot access these properties from within this component `clientGroupMenu`.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post the code for the entire component?

Comment: Is `activeClient` from an API call? We need to see how that's being generated in the parent.

Comment: I believe the problem  isn't `activeClient`. If `this === null` something else is going on

Comment: Guess: `SelectMenu` is a functional component and you're trying to access `this.props` inside it.

Comment: Yeap. Probably he's trying to call `this` and `render` from inside a functional component

Comment: So the error is from source code you're not showing? I mean, you're *not* getting the error on the line where you set the `defaultValue` property if `activeClient` has a value.

Comment: Hi, there's quite a lot in the component to copy / paste. Does what I added help or do you need more context?

Comment: If you can't post the component in a sandbox show us how you're declaring/exporting it

Comment: Have you call the super() like this :

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
And access the props like : 
this.props

Comment: Move out `clientGroupMenu` to be a functional component itself.

Comment: @RahulGupta I have no constructors

Comment: @Shota how is this achieved?

Comment: I've updated some more code

Comment: @GregPeckory simple way to get the data from parent to child is props but you need to call super() in site constructor. Once you should try this way.

Comment: @RahulGupta I call super inside `clientGroupMenu` ? Do I need to extract this out into a class ?

Comment: @GregPeckory Here is sample format : 

// ClientDisplay.js

class ClientDisplay extends Component {
 
 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
 }

 [...]
}

Comment: @RahulGupta what is the significance of `handleChange` here

Comment: @GregPeckory I have given simple format, if you are not using any change/click event remove that for now.

Comment: Please console and share what you are getting in this.props

Comment: How does it look the ````constructor```` method of the component ?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log('client:',JSON.stringify(activeClient,undefined,2));` I suspect async mutation going on.

Comment: I think the issue is in `SelectMenu` could you post that component?

Answer (score 1):

Moving `ClientGroupMenu` into a stateless functional component might help.

```
const ClientGroupMenu = ({activeClient}) => {
  const {groupName} = activeClient

  return (
    <div>
      <SelectMenu
        defaultValue={groupName}
        ...
  )
}


class ClientDisplay extends Component {

  ...

  render() {

    const {activeClient} = this.props

    console.log(activeClient); // This works fine

    return (
      <div><ClientGroupMenu activeClient={activeClient} /></div>
    )

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample format like below you should use [super()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) inside constructor :

```
class ClientDisplay extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    [...]
}
```

If you are getting same error then Use self.props instead of this.props everywhere!

Answer (score -1):

Issue is probably because of destructuring assignment.
Use `const activeClient` declaration instead of `const {activeClient}`

Refer https://itnext.io/using-es6-to-destructure-nested-objects-in-javascript-avoid-undefined-errors-that-break-your-code-612ae67913e9 for more details about destructuring assignment.

When `const {activeClient} = this.props` is used, the actual object's value is copied within activeClient. You have to use `defaultValue={activeClient}` instead of `defaultValue={activeClient.groupName}`

When `const activeClient = this.props` is used,this.props is copied within activeClient. You have to use `defaultValue={activeClient.groupName}` in that case.

Comment: Same error if I use `const activeClient = this.props.activeClient`

Comment: const activeClient = this.props

Comment: @GregPeckory use const activeClient = this.props as said by Sinan.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. It just assigns `props` to `activeClient` as I would expect. Still can't access it inside the component